# How do I access my pages?

Tags: pages

I created pages, but they are not listed under View All Site Content.  How do I find the pages I've created?  I can't believe I can't find anything about this on the Internet.  This seems so basic.

Comment: They are typically going to be in the Pages library or Site Pages library

Comment: Do you have versioning/publishing turned on? Do you need to check them in or publish them?

Comment: I have seen situations where opening the Pages library actually opens the default page (because that page was set as default View), then click Library in the tool bar and click 'All Pages' in the toolbar

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working in, and how did you create the pages? The pages may exist in SitePages, Pages, or at the root folder of the site; only in the last case will they be completely inaccessible via View All Site Content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top left corner of the window select the Site Actions dropdown, then select View All Site Content.
Under Document Libraries, select Site Pages.
[image: Site Pages]

Select the Page tab near the top of your window, and select the View All Pages icon.
[image: View All Pages]

This will display a list of all pages in your site.

This is a ridiculously long way of accessing your pages, and definitely a regression from SP2007, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check Site Pages first or try searching that page and locate its exact url, if you have search working.

Answer (score 1):

They'll be inside the Site Pages library, assuming you are not using the Publishing functions. If you are, they will be in the Pages library.

Answer (score 1):

Here a pic where you can find the way to your "Pages" or "Site Pages".

First click on "Site contents" (1), after that you should see the two libraries (2,3).

[image]

If this helps you, please give it a "vote up" or if it fits perfectly mark it as answer.